# Baja logica ListView C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms

**Buenas, quiero hacer un `Update` a un valor seleccionado en un `ListView` en `C#`. Tengo este método para realizar el `Update` en la **clase conexionSQL**:

```
    public void bajaLogicaCliente(Clientes c)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            string bajaLogica = "UPDATE clientes " +
                "SET idBorrado = 'true' " +
                "WHERE idCliente = @id";
            using(SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(bajaLogica, sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", c.idCliente);

                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Y desde el **Form** lo llamo así:

```
    private void bajaLogica()
    {
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        lstCliente.ValueMember = "idCliente";
        Clientes c = new Clientes();
        c.idCliente = Convert.ToInt32(lstCliente.SelectedValue);
        lstCliente.DataSource = conexionSQL.bajaLogicaCliente(c);
    }
```

Y desde el botón lo aplico:

```
    private void btnBorrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bajaLogica();
        cargarListView();
    }
```

Pero, me sale esto: `No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'void' a 'object'` en esta línea: `lstCliente.DataSource = conexionSQL.bajaLogicaCliente(c);`

¿Alguien me podría decir como lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te indica que en la función `bajaLogicaCliente` espera un parametro del tipo `Clientes` y tu le estas proporcionando un tipo de datos `int`, que corresponde con tu id de cliente.

En este caso pásale todo el objeto `c` que corresponde a tu clase cliente.

```
private void bajaLogica()
    {
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        lstCliente.ValueMember = "idCliente";
        Clientes c = new Clientes();
        c.idCliente = Convert.ToInt32(lstCliente.SelectedValue);
        lstCliente.DataSource = conexionSQL.bajaLogicaCliente(c);
    }
```

Comment: Pues, no. Ahora me dice: `No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'void' en 'objetct'`